# Web api 2 (.net core) Service has deployed in azure server portal getting endpoints response are expired within 1 minute

Tags: .net, azure

Web api Service has deployed in azure portal server getting endpoints are expired within 1 minute.How can i increase the default timeout 60 sec to 15 min in Azure sever portal.But in local working fine for below given method has taken 2 minute 5 sec to get the response.

Please let me know if anyone know this issue.

```
    [HttpGet(@"interval")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(100000000)]
    public IActionResult Interval()
    {
        try
        {
            TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 5);
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
            return Ok("Hello world");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of service ? Web App ? And please give more specific error that Azure showing to you

Comment: yes It is a web api service.In local i am able to get the timeout using abovemethod but once it is deployed server portal time taking one minute after that no response fully blank.can you help to resolve this in issue.

Comment: waiting for 3 min ? You should look at the settings of the hosting IIS

Comment: https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks132/  might be helpfull.